# Chart.js V2. bar chart with a fixed y-axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want my chart to be with horizontal scroll with fixed y-axis.
Found something like this http://jsfiddle.net/mbhavfwm/

```
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
onAnimationComplete: function () {
    var sourceCanvas = this.chart.ctx.canvas;
    var copyWidth = this.scale.xScalePaddingLeft - 5;
    // the +5 is so that the bottommost y axis label is not clipped off
    // we could factor this in using measureText if we wanted to be generic
    var copyHeight = this.scale.endPoint + 5;
    var targetCtx = document.getElementById("myChartAxis").getContext("2d");
    targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth;
    targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
}});
```

for v.1, but the code seems different for v.2

I don't see a parameter or option for this in the docs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to modify the existing code mentioned in the fiddle with following code. This might help you work with v2.

```
animation: {
    onComplete: function(data) {
        var getParentIdName = this.chart.canvas.attributes.id.value,
        targetElement = document.getElementById("virtual-chart-axis"),
        sourceElement = document.getElementById("organizational-view"),
        sourceCanvas = this.chart.ctx.canvas,
        copyWidth = this.scales["y-axis-0"].width, // we are copying the width of actual chart
        copyHeight = this.chart.height, // we are copying the width of actual chart
        targetElementWidth = sourceElement.getContext("2d").canvas.clientWidth,
        targetElementHeight = sourceElement.getContext("2d").canvas.clientHeight,
        targetCtx = targetElement.getContext("2d");

        targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth;
        targetCtx.canvas.height = copyHeight;
        targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, targetElementWidth, targetElementHeight);
    }
}
```

Good Luck.